Can a mathematical theory ever be disconfirmed by experience?
This is technically a two-part question:

Has anyone ever claimed that a particular mathematical theory was empirically disconfirmed?
What would count as an empirical disconfirmation of a pure mathematical theory?

Empiricists about mathematics probably have a lot to say about this, but I
don't personally know whether there is any succinct and clear discussion on this very specific issue.

According to “Really Full-Blooded Platonism” by JC Bealle, all mathematical objects including inconsistent ones exist. I’d argue this gives the mathematician total freedom from disconfirmation.

@JKusin Thanks for the headsup on https://entailments.net/papers/fbplatonism.pdf Seems excessively permisive!

What do you mean by “mathematical theory”? If you mean theorem, then that’s a proposition for which a valid proof exists, so empirical observations are irrelevant to its correctness. The extent of its applicability maybe, but not its correctness. And if you do mean theory, then that’s a body of techniques and results (like number theory or graph theory) and therefore not susceptible—as a whole entity—to either confirmation or disconfirmation.

IMHO, that would turn mathematics into a natural science, which it's not, it's a formal science! Very interesting question!

All of Lakatos' Proofs and Refutations is towards this goal — empiricising the process of mathematical discovery. Or rather unveiling that in actual math progress always by empirical verification and counterexample. See also SEP

@PaulTanenbaum Although empirical data might lead one to suspect a proof is flawed. I don't know of any specific cases where that happened, though. (But I'd be surprised if there weren't a few "that can't be right; I should double check this before publishing" moments from time to time.)

Seems like in order for this question to make sense you would need a definition of what “empirical disconfirmation” means, but I’m skeptical that this is coherently definable. You might try to argue that using a computer to brute-force search for a counter-example to a theorem is “empirical”, but how is that essentially different than a person thinking of a counter-example in their head?

If by "Theory" you mean "theorem", or "mutually consistent set of propositions" then no because mathematical theorems and formal systems are deductively true.
However, I'm guessing you are taking it to mean a more provisional statement. In mathematics, such statements are called conjectures (i.e., the mathematical equivalent of a scientific hypothesis and theories).
In that case, yes! For example, take the Collatz Conjecture: Even the great Terrence Tao could only derive a probabilistic result to this one!

Warning: The Collatz Conjecture is dangerous -- many a mathematician have been lured in by its deceiving simplicity, never to return ;-)

Collatz Algorithm:  - Set n:=0  - Pick an integer an > 0.  1a. If an is even, then set an+1 = an/2 and go to step 2 1b. If an is odd, then set an+1 = 3an + 1 
2. If an+1 = 1, stop; else, go to step 3. 
3. n ← n + 1 
4. Go to step 1


Collatz Conjecture: Regardless of what number we choose for a0, there is an n such that an=1

We still do not know if this conjecture is true, but we know that it is almost surely true thanks to Tao.
Wikipedia has collected a ton of examples fitting your criteria.

+1 I love me some Collatz!

@JD yeah, I've fallen victim to it myself - number theory conjectures are the "Othello" of mathematics -- minutes to understand, a lifetime to solve

Excellent answer.

Empiricism in mathematics is a controversial topic. Linnebo devotes his sixth chapter (GB) to what it even means to be empirical in mathematics, covering Mill and Quine's views on the topic, as well as Quine's indispensability argument (SEP) where the interrelation of empirical science and mathematics is explored. Mathematical explanation (SEP), for instance, is indispensable as is argued for scientific explanation.
But if you mean by empirical mathematics, the use of mathematical constructivism (SEP) to ascertain existence, or the use of the automation of computation to discover mathematical truths that cannot possibly known a priori, then you might want to consider an accessible class of mathematical claims of the form 'X is a prime number' and the use of the Sieve of Eratosthenes implemented in a computer language.
If you make the claim some sufficiently large number, like 12,342,127,551 is a prime number, then it would seem there is no simple way to know without learning by experience. If the number ended in 2, it can be ruled out instantly because of a divisibility rule. We might also check if the digits sum to a number divisible by 3. But baring it is an exceptional number that has some quick algebraic proof like in the case of the even, the number can only shown to be prime if all divisors up to about the square root are tried. Thus, the claim itself can only be shown true through trial and error, and is therefore arguably an a posteriori truth. In fact, the entire sequence of primes to some prime p for sufficiently large primes must be constructed by an algorithm like the Sieve of Eratosthenes. This would seem to fit the definition of an empirical process in the broader sense of requiring experimentation particularly for primes so large, especially when complex software itself must be implemented by trial and error.
Of course, what it means to justify with a priori truths is quite the sticky wicket, and there is controversy particularly because the traditional notion of a priori justification rests on the analytic-synthetic distinction which was claimed by Quine and others to be flawed. When dealing with small propositions, such "2+3=5" it is much clearer that certain truths might be considered a priori. Can the same be said of justification that relies on extremely complex computations? From the IEP's article A Priori and A Posteriori:

To say that a person knows a given proposition a priori is to say that her justification for believing this proposition is independent of experience. According to the traditional view of justification, to be justified in believing something is to have an epistemic reason to support it, a reason for thinking it is true. Thus, to be a priori justified in believing a given proposition is to have a reason for thinking that the proposition is true that does not emerge or derive from experience. By contrast, to be a posteriori justified is to have a reason for thinking that a given proposition is true that does emerge or derive from experience.

Thus, it seems fair to say that "2+2=4" is true independent of experience, but the sum of two 20-digit numbers is not. Where does one draw the line? So, of course, as all things philosophical, the debates surrounding how to use the terms 'a priori' and 'a posteriori', 'rational' and 'empirical', and invoking them to argue for logicism, formalism, empiricism, intuitionism, and structuralism (to name some well known positions), can be complex, and therefore "experimental mathematics" and the relationship between mathematics and empirical methods, as well as deductive, inductive, and abductive reasoning is controversial.
You ask:

Can a mathematical theory ever be disconfirmed by experience?

Disconfirmation of mathematical theories happens by the detection of errors. Are those errors of mathematics and logic detected in some empirical fashion? It is hard to see how an argument could be made that Wiles's error could be known a priori. Consider from WP:

Wiles first announced his proof on 23 June 1993 at a lecture in Cambridge entitled "Modular Forms, Elliptic Curves and Galois Representations".2 However, in September 1993 the proof was found to contain an error.

If one frames empirical mathematics in such a way, then it is arguable that Andrew Wiles's original proof of Fermat's Last Theorem was disproven empirically by a detection of a mathematical deficiency. That is, in complex mathematical proofs, any detection of error or a failure of mathematical rigor, occurs according to the experience and insights of working with proofs, and does not happen in a purely a priori manner, and seemingly all disconfirmation of proposed theories is empirical.

Very helpful answer. And thanks for the pointer to Linnebo!

To be fair, it's not exactly exception that a very large number chosen completely at random can be quickly known to be non-prime. 60% of such numbers can be identified simply by looking at the last digit! (I.e., those ending in 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, or 8.) Another third can be identified by looking at the sum of the digits, and there's a trivial differencing technique for identifying those divisible by 11. So, about three-fourths can be trivially identified as being non-prime, and I'm probably neglecting some other techniques. That said, your answer is helpful, and I do understand your point.

I mentioned the above only because you wrote "But baring it is an exceptional number that has some quick algebraic proof like in the case of the even, the number can only shown to be prime if all divisors up to about the square root are tried." I do get the point that it's difficult to show a randomly chosen very large prime number is, indeed, prime.

Certainly. Patterns can seem to hold until a counterexample has been found. Some examples are cited in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_mathematics
